# awk: print whole line (string with spaces) into BASH array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, text-processing

$ cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
                      HDA Intel MID at 0xb0610000 irq 64
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xb0614000 irq 65
```

I am trying to save the second line of each entry into a BASH array:

```
eval sound_card_array=($(awk 'NR%2==0' /proc/asound/cards)) #also tried without eval -> same result

#echo $(awk 'NR%2==0' /proc/asound/cards) --> this produces the proper output of each line
```

which should look like this:

```
["HDA Intel MID at 0xb0610000 irq 64", "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb0614000 irq 65"]
```

Instead, when I print out sound_card_array, I get only parts of the strings, or I get them all in different array elements.  I have tried putting quotes around the awk call, adding echo, putting quotes around the variable when I access the array (i.e. "${sound_card_array[$i]}"), but none work.

UPDATE:  Thanks guys.  Maybe my problem is also with the way I'm accessing the array:

```
for sc in "${!sound_card_array[@]}"
do
        if [ "$sc" -lt "$((${#sound_card_array[@]}-1))" ]; then
                j_pair $sc "${sound_card_array[$i]}"
        else
                j_pair_last $sc "${sound_card_array[$i]}"
        fi

done
```

where j_pair and j_pair_last are BASH functions I wrote which take two arguments and echo them to a file:

```
function j_pair {
        printTabs
        echo  "\"$1\":\"$2\","
}
function j_pair_last {
        printTabs
        echo  "\"$1\":\"$2\""
}
```

I'm new to BASH, so I'm sure there are many things I could be doing wrong.  Thanks again for all the help!

For awk and printf:

```
$ arr=($(awk 'NR%2==0{$1=$1; print}' /proc/asound/cards))
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"

HDA
Intel
MID
at
0xb0610000
irq
64
HDA
Intel
PCH
at
0xb0614000
irq
65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using Bash:

```
sound_card_array=() i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    (( i++ % 2 )) && sound_card_array+=("${line:22}")
done < /proc/asound/cards
```

Test:

```
sound_card_array=() i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    (( i++ % 2 )) && sound_card_array+=("${line:22}")
done < sample.txt
printf '%s\n' "${sound_card_array[@]}"
```

Output:

```
HDA Intel MID at 0xb0610000 irq 64
HDA Intel PCH at 0xb0614000 irq 65
```

Comment: All BASH!  Probably even better.  Every time I searched for how to read only the second line of a file, people always showed awk solutions.  However, when I iterate through the array with 

'for sc in "${!sound_card_array[@]}" '

I get an empty element at the end.

Comment: @MrUser Test shows well. Any different thing you might have made? Perhaps update your question with it?

Comment: You're right!  It did work.  After anubhava helped me see that I was using the wrong iterator in my for loop ($i instead of $sc because I was looking at examples that used $i and forgot to update...gulp), and after you updated your code with the (( i++ % 2 )), it all works.  Awesome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem is in your use of `eval`**.

You don't need to (and must not) use `eval` to create an array from awk's output in BASH. Use `IFS` while assigning it to an array:

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=($(awk 'NR%2==0{$1=$1; print}' /proc/asound/cards))
```

**PS:** I used `$1=$1` to make awk reformat and strip out all leading space in 2nd line.

Then to test:

```
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
HDA Intel MID at 0xb0610000 irq 64
HDA Intel PCH at 0xb0614000 irq 65
```

Comment: I didn't know that $1=$1 would strip out all the leading spaces!  I was using gsub, and very awkwardly I might add.  However, this still didn't work for me.  Maybe it's because of the way I'm accessing the elements. (see my update above)

Comment: What do you get when you use `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"` command?

Comment: I looked at your script and looks like `for sc in "${!sound_card_array[@]}"` is the problem. You need to use: `for sc in "${sound_card_array[@]}"` here

Comment: But wouldn't that give me the value, and not the index?  If I do that, then sc is the string itself and I can't print out the array iterator value.  I access the value by using ${sound_card_array[$sc]}, but you did show me that I was using $i instead of $sc!  Oops.

Comment: Actually, the printf statement printed all the words on different lines.  Echo worked with your code, but it still doesn't work in the array.  Although konsolebox's answer works for me, I would like to figure this out in case I need stronger text manipulation in the future (and want to use awk).  If you're still willing to help with the awk solution, I very much appreciate it.

Comment: Sure I can only help with the awk solution but you didn't answer my direct questions. Please see comment #2 above.

Comment: ok see updated answer and use: `IFS=$'\n' arr=($(awk 'NR%2==0{$1=$1; print}' /proc/asound/cards))`

Comment: Great to know. IMO this is much safer than using substring of 22 chars later. What if you get an input with variable # of spaces some day. For striping leading spaces in BASH use: `shopt -s extglob; echo "${line##+([[:blank:]])}"`

Comment: I didn't know about the globbing feature.  Thanks again: +1.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 options :

If the number of word is constant :

```
sound_card_array=($(awk 'NR%2==0' cards ))

echo ${sound_card_array[@]:0:7}
HDA Intel MID at 0xb0610000 irq 64

echo ${sound_card_array[@]:7:7}
HDA Intel PCH at 0xb0614000 irq 65
```

Or :

```
sound_card_array=($(awk 'NR%2==0{$1=$1;a=$0; gsub(" +","_",a); print a}' cards ))

echo ${sound_card_array[0]} | tr "_" " "
HDA Intel MID at 0xb0610000 irq 64

echo ${sound_card_array[1]} | tr "_" " "
HDA Intel PCH at 0xb0614000 irq 65
```

Hope this helps